# Is it good to work in Connected or Disconnected from Source control

Tags: version-control, visual-sourcesafe

I have always found it a matter of Debate; If the "**Programmer should work in Connected or in Disconnected mode."**  in VSS (Exclusive lock).
With my exprience I have found it's much more error proof and efficient to work with connected mode always, as you don't need to keep track of modifield code files.
Though this will refrain other users from checking out the same file and make changes. 
I want to know the standards that can be followed while working with VSS for checking out and checking in and modifying.

Note: I know the difference with Subversion and CVS which allow multiple checkouts. I need views when VSS administrator is allowing u will mutual Exclusive.

I appreciate each views..

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think more valid name for what you call "connected" is "lock-modify-unlock" (VSS-style) vs "copy-modify-merge" (SVN-style).

Now, as to when to use what (I assume this is what you're asking), it depends on the nature of files being edited. Binary files and files that do not allow for easy merging are best locked prior to actual edit. Pure text files can be merged just fine, and DVCSes prove this point.